# Check if path refers to a directory, even if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to be able to distinguish two cases in a command line utility:

1. The user has specified an output directory (`-o output/`): create a file called `output/file.ext`
2. The user has specified an output file (`-o output`): create a file called `output`

What's the correct way in C++17 to determine that `output/` or `output\` is a path to a directory **even when the `output` directory doesn't exist**?

The free function `std::filesystem::is_directory()` returns false unless the directory exists.

Is checking that `std::filesystem::path::has_filename()` returns false reliable?

Edit: clarified use case based on comments.

Comment: If you mean before *anything* exists then you can't from just a string value: A file name does not need to have an extension.  A directory name is allowed to have an extension.   The same path is valid for both.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, how you can know what classification it would have had if it did? This question is impossible. Sounds to me more like you need to focus on path parsing. `!has_filename()` sounds like a good idea, assuming the input string has a trailing separator I suppose; have you had a problem with it?

Comment: If all you want to do is see if the final path segment has a name or not, you could just ask `has_stem`. Whether that means "is a directory" is up to your interpretation.

Comment: I'd ask what you're really trying to accomplish. You didn't say.

Comment: Both the directories `.` and `..` will report `true` when using `has_filename()`

Comment: The first two comments are wrong. Even if `foof` doesn't exist, `ls > foof/` will return "foof/ is a directory". A name with a terminating slash is not a legal file name but is a legal directory name.

Comment: I agree with @DavidSchwartz, the first two comments are wrong. Note the trailing forward/backward slashes in my question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's interesting and clearly a shortcoming of my "solution". Thanks!

Comment: Is what you're asking then "would this be a valid path for creating a directory if it doesn't already exist?"  .  I see what you mean that if you add the "/" or "\" it can't be a file, but my point was that the rest of the string is ambiguous (undecideable) unless the object exists.

Comment: If the question is whether creating a directory with this name would succeed, I'd just try it and see. If necessary, remove the directory afterwards. The use case isn't explained, but this feels like an attempt to guarantee that a future operation will succeed where it likely makes more sense to try it since you can never really guarantee it anyway. (Because it can fail for so many weird reasons you can't easily foresee.)

Comment: The use case is the one of a command line utility: has the user specified an output directory or an output file? I've edited the question to clarify the use case.

Comment: It's a somewhat unusual interface. Why not let the user supply the output filename and you just try to create it? If it fails because the directory doesn't exist, the user needs to create the directory. That's the common way to deal with this and doing it another way is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible even theoretically, because if the user specified a path whose last element is non-existent, it could be created either as a file or as a directory.

However, you can check the special case of a path ending in a directory separator (`std::path::preferred_separator`), which can happen only for directories, not regular files. That's pretty easy to do.